# Hiding columns in code generated WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I got problem with WPF DataGrid.
I try to empty datagrid, add columns and fill it with data from database , and than hide 1 column which is id that user don't need to see.

But when i try, it says that DataGrid columnsCount is 0, even after adding everything at the end of method.
I even tried to hide it in another method after doing 1st one, but still same error.
So my trick to do it is very messy and i want to learn how to do it in better way.

this is my simple code inserting columns etc. to DataGrid:

```
private void insertSubjects()
{
    DataSet dataSet = DBConnect.Instance.getSubjects();
    DataTable subjects = new DataTable();
    subjects.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
    subjects.Columns.Add("Przedmiot", typeof(string));

    foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            subjects.Rows.Add(row["id"], row["name"]);
        }
    }

    subjectsTable.ItemsSource = subjects.DefaultView;
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(hideColumns)).Start();
}
```

My fixing here is new thread that executing method, which execute another one because I need to do it by Dispatcher.Invoke which looks like this:

```
private void hideColumns()
{
    while (subjectsTable.Columns.Count == 0)
    { }
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(hideColumns2);
}
private void hideColumns2()
{
    subjectsTable.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Problem is when I had on 1 Page or Window , 2 other DataGrids, and if I want to hide columns in both of them, i had to fill them in one method.

I tried to find answer for this, but I failed, and fixed in my way.

Comment: Delete all that and use proper XAML and DataBinding.

Comment: @HighCore with a dose of MVVM thrown in for good measure I presume?

Comment: @DavidL that's precisely what I said. XAML + DataBinding == MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've programmed it, I would recommend creating a datacolumn object then inserting that datacolumn object into datatable. With that you can reference the datacolumn using its location.

```
...
DataTable subjects = new DataTable();
DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn("id", typeof(int));
// You can set various properties of the DataColumn.
// MSDN Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1tyd60z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

subject.Columns.Add(idColumn);
```

Now you should be able to access the specific column to reference the actual DataColumn object. It's a pseudo binding trick that I've used in the past.